# Where exactly do I go for the Death Symbolized quest?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've been trying to get to the quest marker for Chapter 2's Death Symbolized quest in The Witcher 2. Every time I start walking in the direction where its leading me I end up back on the wraith invested battlefield; which is an entirely different map. I tried backtracking to the spot where the guards won't let me pass all the way into Vergen. From there I only see a path that takes me down into a harpy-ridden ravine which offers pretty much a dead end.

I've tried going through Vergen but the city is totally blocked off at both entrances. I must be missing a passage way or something before the city gates. Where exactly am I supposed to go for this quest?

Comment: Iorveth or Roche's path?

Comment: For Roche's path.

Comment: Can you climb up onto the cities walls? There's a path through there to behind the city which leads to a whole new area (with the catacombs you seek). I haven't played through on Roche's path yet, so that's about as much as I can help ya.

Comment: You're exactly right. I climbed up on the walls and went right instead of left and was in an entirely different area. If you want to put that as an answer I'll happily upvote it for you. Thanks so much! I can't believe I didn't think to do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make it to the catacombs, which are, as you mentioned, misleading to get to.

What you need to do is climb up onto the walls of Vergen, then head left of the city proper. You should travel through a section of slums, and then through a door that leads to a wooded area beyond. This eventually leads to a wooded area where the Catacombs are located for the Dun Banner (Death Symbolized) quests, and is also where you find the place of magic (As per Skalon's instructions) and the kidnapped victim's corpses (A Flickering Heart). (The latter two are Iorveth-path exclusive quests.